# How do I apply use Full Join without creating nulls?

Tags: sql, join, oracle11g

I have a requirement in Oracle 11c. I have the below 3 tables where I need to join these 3 tables based on `CUSTOMER_ID` column and show dates without creating duplicate rows.

[image]

When I use the FULL join, I am not getting the expected output. ie, in the last row, CUSTOMER_ID column is null.

[image]

The expected output is like below. ie, even if `DEV_DATES` has more rows or `TEST_DATES` has more rows, it should show all dates based on the `CUSTOMER_ID`.

[image]

Note that there is no relation between the dates in the `DEV_DATES` and `TEST_DATES` values. The relation is only with the `CUSTOMER_ID`. For getting dates in the same row, I used `ROW_NUMBER()` function.

```
WITH CUSTOMERS AS
(
    SELECT 1 AS CUSTOMER_ID FROM DUAL
    UNION
    SELECT 2 AS CUSTOMER_ID FROM DUAL
)
,DEV_DATES AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CUSTOMER_ID ORDER BY DEV_RUN_DATE) AS RNO, T.*
    FROM
    (
        SELECT 1 AS CUSTOMER_ID, TO_DATE('5 Jan 2017', 'DD MON YYYY') AS DEV_RUN_DATE FROM DUAL
        UNION
        SELECT 1 AS CUSTOMER_ID, TO_DATE('12 Jan 2017', 'DD MON YYYY') AS DEV_RUN_DATE FROM DUAL        
    ) T
)
,TEST_DATES AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CUSTOMER_ID ORDER BY TEST_RUN_DATE) AS RNO, T.*
    FROM
    (
        SELECT 1 AS CUSTOMER_ID, TO_DATE('8 Jan 2017', 'DD MON YYYY') AS TEST_RUN_DATE FROM DUAL
        UNION
        SELECT 1 AS CUSTOMER_ID, TO_DATE('23 Jan 2017', 'DD MON YYYY') AS TEST_RUN_DATE FROM DUAL
        UNION
        SELECT 1 AS CUSTOMER_ID, TO_DATE('27 Jan 2017', 'DD MON YYYY') AS TEST_RUN_DATE FROM DUAL
    ) T
)
SELECT DISTINCT CUST.CUSTOMER_ID,DEV.DEV_RUN_DATE,TEST.TEST_RUN_DATE
FROM CUSTOMERS CUST
LEFT JOIN DEV_DATES DEV ON DEV.CUSTOMER_ID = CUST.CUSTOMER_ID
FULL JOIN TEST_DATES TEST ON TEST.CUSTOMER_ID = DEV.CUSTOMER_ID AND DEV.RNO = TEST.RNO
ORDER BY CUST.CUSTOMER_ID
```

Comment: Debug questions require a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code including initialization; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. [ask] [Help] When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. (Debugging fundamental.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `COALESCE` and select the first non null `CUSTOMER_ID`:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
    COALESCE(CUST.CUSTOMER_ID, TEST.CUSTOMER_ID) AS CUSTOMER_ID,
    DEV.DEV_RUN_DATE,
    TEST.TEST_RUN_DATE
FROM CUSTOMERS CUST
LEFT JOIN DEV_DATES DEV ON DEV.CUSTOMER_ID = CUST.CUSTOMER_ID
FULL JOIN TEST_DATES TEST
    ON TEST.CUSTOMER_ID = DEV.CUSTOMER_ID AND DEV.RNO = TEST.RNO
ORDER BY CUST.CUSTOMER_ID;
```